# I cannot get object properties as function

Tags: javascript, object, properties, nested

Halo guys.. I'm quite new here in this site, so any help would be appreciated. please let me know if my question already exists in another topic. i have the following problem.. i create an object which has another object. the child object has some properties. whenever i iterate the child object to get the properties, it seems all of the properties are of string type.. below are my codes:

```
    var obj = {}
    obj.x = function(){
        this.y = function(){

        }
    }

    for(var a in obj){
        alert(typeof(a) === "string"); //this will be true
        alert(a.hasOwnProperty("y")); //this will be false
    }
```

I use chrome to test this. shouldn't it be that typeof(a) === "function" is true and that a.hasOwnProperty("y") is also true?
I cannot see my mistakes here. I'm quite lost.. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`obj.x` is a function, if you want to use the function as a constructor for an object try

```
obj.x = new (function(){
    this.y = function(){

    }
})();
```

also  your test is wrong, `a` is just a string so ofcourse it wouldn't have a `y` property.

```
for(var a in obj){
    alert(typeof(obj[a]) === "object");  
    alert(obj[a].hasOwnProperty("y"));  
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. :D.. i just edited my question.. shouldn't it be that typeof(a) === "function" is true and that a.hasOwnProperty("y") is also true?

Comment: `a` is a property(or key) so it can only be a string or a number.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var a in obj){
        alert(typeof(a) === "string"); //this will be true
}
```

For...in loops in javascript iterate over the property names of an object, not the properties themselves. So `a` will return the names of each property which will always be strings

In your example obj has one property `x`, so the loop will run once with `a` equal to `"x"`

If you want to iterate over the properties of the object, you can do this

```
for(var a in obj){
    var property = obj[a];
        alert(typeof( property) === "string"); //this will be false
}
```